# Why only one folder was pushed to github repo on git push -u origin main?

Tags: git, github

I have a root folder named `learn-testing` and two child folders `client` and `server`.

Here is the folder structure:

```
 -learn-testing
     -client
     -server
```

Here is the code I ran to push my code to my github repo:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "login frontend and backend implementation"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https: ..............................
git push -u origin main
```

The code did got pushed to my github repo but only the `server` folder code. A folder for `client` was made but its icon has a arrow in it and there is not code.

Here is the created folder image:

[image]

Now when I try to run the following instructions:

```
git add .
git commit -m "adding client code``
```

On `git status` I am getting the following instruction in my command prompt:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   client (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Please guide me on why only half of my code was pushed and also on how to push the client folder code to GitHub

Comment: Is the folder empty?

Comment: Can you show the full output of `git status`? As text please, not as an image

Comment: @tymtam, I added the result for git status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+white+arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `client` is a git repo as well. Is it possible that you run `git init` in `client` by mistake?

The solution is be to delete `.git` directory from the `client` folder.